# Source for purchasing an authentic set of the Arizal's writings?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, arizal

Where can I purchase kisve Arizal from an authentic source?

Comment: What is the question? Is there a question of accuracy, or is there concern that it was printed with improper intent? Is the question something else?

Comment: @Avrah I looked on amazon and found a set from the kabalah center so I wanna make sure I'm getting from a kosher source

Comment: Are you looking for his own writings or writings of his students such as R Hayim Vital?

Answer (score 1):

I have [this exact set](https://www.mitzvahland.com/products/kitvei-arizal-set-of-15-books-writings-by-rabbi-isaac-luria-the-arizal-haari-hakadosh-kabbalah), which I purchased along with my Rosh Kollel when he was stocking up for the beit midrash. While I did not purchase it from this seller, the fact that it is the same edition from the same publisher would seem to indicate that it is authentic. Please note that this edition is entirely bereft of commentaries or other meforshim, so it may or may not be what you're looking for.

Publisher info here:

[image: this page includes info on the publisher]

You could also try this edition, which includes meforshim. I am not sure where one would purchase it online [image: Sefer Eitz Chaim from this series]
[image: publisher info]

Comment: Are there editions that have meforshim?

Comment: Yes. This series is quite popular: https://mysefer.com/Rabbi-Yitzchak-Luria---HaAri-1534-1572--Rabbi-Chaim-Vital-1543-1620/Shaar-HaGilgulim---Peirush-Matok-MiDvash-vol.-1__p-139-2950.aspx

Comment: This series is also becoming more and more popular: https://mysefer.com/Rabbi-Yitzchak-Luria---HaAri-1534-1572--Rabbi-Chaim-Vital-1543-1620/Kitvei-HaAri---Shaar-HaGilgulim-Shaarei-Yitzchak-Edition__p-139-9169.aspx

Comment: just the one sefer and not a whole set? Is there something that would have the main text in the center with multiple commentaries around it? something like the way shulchan aruch is set up

Comment: @Dude in both cases I put in the comments the whole set exists but is not for sale on that website. There is indeed an edition laid out like the Shulchan Aruch or Gemarra with lots of meforshim surrounding the text but I do not recall the name of the publisher. bli neder I will get over this bad headcold tonight and head to the beit midrash tomorrow and take some pics of that edition for you

Comment: Refua. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, @Dude. I think the edition I added just now should be what you're looking for. Let me know if the publisher info is not clear enough and I can reshoot that photo